# Prove that if $K$ is a strictly increasing function, then $K(i)\geq i$ for all $i$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

This seems a very statement to be proven, but I'm stuck. I'm trying the contradiction technique:

Take $i>j$. Then, we know that $K(i) > K(j)$. Suppose for the sake of obtaining a contradiction that $K(i) < i$. I can't follow from here. Any hints?

Comment: Proof by induction.

Comment: The function K(i) = i - 1 is a strictly increasing function and K(i) = i - 1 < i for all i. So the statement is false without some other assumption on K. For example, does K only take values in the natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's right! I will edit it. It only takes values on natural numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a strictly increasing function, that is, $K(n) \geq K(n-1) + 1$, and $K(1) \geq 1$.

> Claim: $$K(i) \geq i \quad  \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$$

**Base Step**: $K(1) \geq 1$.

**Induction Step:**

> $$K(i+1) \geq K(i) + 1 \geq i + 1. $$

Comment: @kobe better ? :P

Comment: It's all good. :)